# Aurelia support for XML

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

Will support be provided for XML file reads/writes? If I read the Aurelia docs correctly, Aurelia-fetch-client and aurelia-http-client, are configured for/expecting JSON response types (HTTP Services in Aurelia docs). I have a very large SPA conversion project and want to use Aurelia. However, all the page content and pointers are output in an XML document and mapped via GUIDs. Do I need to build a custom routine for XML to JSON for use with Aurelia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fetch API specification currently doesn't have any methods to take/ convert the response stream as XML Document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods). (The same fetch API is used by Aurelia if the browser supports it or it uses a polyfill (whatwg fetch) that implements matching logic to the API)

What you can do is get the stream as text and then parse the output with a library that can parse XML.

For example with jQuery's parseXML (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method:

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@autoinject
export class XMLFetchTest {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .useStandardConfiguration()
        .withBaseUrl('/src/');
    });
  }

  public activate() {
    return this.http.fetch('test.xml')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        let doc = $.parseXML(text);
      }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured it was going to be something like this. I was really hoping to avoid Angular - seems like this is the solution. I just wish there was something in the framework.